Help me find this comedy movie about a guy in a wheelchair
My friend said that she watched a very funny movie about a guy who pulled his groin in some type accident and though he is healed after a few weeks, he decides to stay in the wheelchair because by doing so, he gets the attention of a woman. She doesn't know what the movie is called and her husband thinks that it is non existent.  Please help.  It may get me a free dinner.

Found it, the movie is Coming & Going from 2011:
Here is the plot including all elements from your question:

Lee (Rhys Darby) is a young, skilled OBGYN who lacks confidence when it comes to talking to women outside his successful medical practice. A minor injury temporarily lands him in a wheelchair and it is at that precise time that he meets his dream girl Alex (Sasha Alexander). Convinced she's only paid attention to him because he's in that chair, he stays in it to win her affections well after his injury has healed.

The trailer: 


Enjoy your free dinner :-)
